# How to install Android packages in android buildozer(kivy framework)?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy

I created the kivy program. I have set the buildozer.
But I get this error:
*Check configuration tokens Unknown command/target android*

My question is where is android sdk in buildozer? I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html):

> Buildozer currently works only in Linux, and is a beta release, but it
> already works well and can significantly simplify the apk build.